# Nested pages with routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to make nested pages (like when the one page(page1) is a parent for the other page(page2), and routes for these pages looks like: `site.com/page1/page2`. What gem should help me to do that ?

Comment: So the url for page 7 would be: `page1/page2/page3/page4/page5/page6/page7`?

Comment: if its a child for page6 - yes

Comment: Is the relation between page 7 and page 6 defined in the model or only through the url? If it is defined in the model, there is no need to reflect that in the url.

Comment: I need to reflect that in the url, that's part of task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is a gem for this, but I would start with a route something like:

```
get 'pages/*parents/:page', to: 'pages#show'
```

The URL `site.com/pages/page1/page2/page3` will be parsed to the params:

```
params[:parents] = 'page1/page2'
params[:page] = 'page3'
```

Now you can do something like:

```
parent_names = params[:parents].split('/')
```

Not sure if this is what you want but I hope it will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

This is not common good practice. I'm not saying you should not do it as I don't know anything about your business logic but the usual practice is

```
/model_name/:id/model_name/:id
```

with at most one level of nesting. That means no such things as

```
/model_name/:id/model_name/:id/model_name/:id
```

In general, I favour the shortest possible path. Hence, if the resource can be identified with just its `id`, I go with `/model_name/:id`.
This often results in things such as

```
resources :post do
  resources :comments, only: [:new, :create]
end

resources :comments, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

I hope that helped.